# Custom 403 error page in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-templates, http-status-code-403

I am trying to override the default 403.html template of django rest framework, by declaring in ulrs.py `handler403 = 'my_app.views.handler403'`.

And in the app's views.py:

```
def handler403(request, exception, template_name='403.html'):
    response = render_to_response('403.html', {})
    response.status_code = 403
    return response
```

The template's directory is included in TEMPLATE_DIRS in settings.py.
However, making a request to an endpoint that has **IsAdminUser** permission, renders the default drf template.

The **same exact** procedure for the 404 exception works perfectly fine.

Any answer I saw in the web did not help me resolve the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite simple actually:

You have to overwrite 'custom_exception_handler' of the DRF just like below:

```
from Django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def custom_exception_handler(...):
    response = render_to_response('path/to/template/403.html', {})
    response.status_code = 403
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because DRF returns a json response, does not render a template.

Comment: So any solution to my problem?

Comment: Depends, do you really want to return an HTML response instead of a JSON response as a part of your api?

Comment: Yes, when a 403 appears I want to render a custom template

Comment: Ok following this answer https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/344112 I think if you share your view I can help you with it. Please edit your question with your view code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def handler403(request, exception, template_name='403.html'):
    return render(request, '403.html')
```